Spend money on vs Spend money for
What are the differences between spend money "on" vs spend money "for"? Is using "for" even grammatically correct? I have seen a video in which a person says "If I gave you $100, what would you spend it for?" Is it grammatically correct or not? Does it sound natural to say "spend money for"?
Edit:
The video link is: https://www.facebook.com/EdulinePhilippines/videos/1636330590488620
The speaker does not appear to be a native speaker, but it seems to be an advertisement from an English learning center.

"What would you spend it for?" is syntactically invalid, so this looks like a "non-question". Is your source even a native Anglophone? Without more "evidence of occurrence", I see nothing to respond to.

Please include the link to the video in your question otherwise it risks being closed-

I think that would also depend on the answer. 'What would you spend it on?' would directly tell you to answer concrete items. While, 'What would you spend it for?' would also lead to an answer of an item, but it would lead to a personal outcome... like being happy... "I would spend it for my own happiness." "I would spend it for satisfaction."


"On", in this kind of context, is used to indicate what something is used for.

"For" is used to indicate purpose.


Asking "What did you spend your money on?" would mean you want to know what items they bought, because that is what the money was used for.
Asking "What did you spend your money for?" would mean you want to know why they spent the money - what was the purpose of spending it.
Remember that the prepositions are working with the question "what", so the questions about the money could be broken down to "what on" and "what for". Oxford defines the latter as "for what reason?".
